# $T \cdot W=0$ for every skew symmetric tensor $T$ implies that $T$ is a symmetric tensor

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, tensors, symmetry

I'm trying to prove by myself the following easy fact. The context is continuum mechanics (in particular I'm using Gurtin's book):

> Let $T$ a tensor and $W%$ a skew-symmetric tensor. If $T \cdot W =0 $ for every $ W \in \text{Skw}$, then $T$ is symmetric.

---

I can't obtain $T=T^t$ by using the definition, but I can't.

$T \cdot W = \text{tr}(T^t W)=\text{tr}(T^t (W^t) ^t) =- \text{tr}(T^t W^t) = -\text{tr}(W^t T^t)=-W \cdot T^t$
so I have $$T \cdot W + W \cdot T^t =0$$

and I don't know how to get the thesis $T=T^t$. How should I move?

Comment: Given a vector space $V$, you can prove ${\rm End}(V)$ is an orthogonal direct sum of the symmetric and skew-symmetric operators. This forces anything orthogonal to all skew-symmetric operators is a symmetric operator, and vice-versa.

Comment: @runway44 I know, but I am supposed to use the definition with $\text{trace}$ given in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Every linear operator $T$ is uniquely expressible as a combination $T=T_\mathrm{sym}+T_\mathrm{skew}$ of a symmetric operator and a skew-symmetric operator. Indeed, we can apply the adjoint to both sides and solve the system

$$ \begin{cases}
T & =T_\mathrm{sym}+T_\mathrm{skew} \\ T^\dagger &=T_\mathrm{sym}-T_\mathrm{skew}
\end{cases} $$

to yield the formulas

$$ T_\mathrm{sym}=\frac{1}{2}(T+T^\dagger), \qquad T_\mathrm{skew}=\frac{1}{2}(T-T^\dagger). $$

Not only is the vector space $\mathrm{End}(V)$ a direct sum of the subspaces of symmetric and skew-symmetric operators, this is an *orthogonal* direct sum. We verify orthogonality using the definition of the Frobenius-Schmidt inner product of two linear operators an an inner product space: $\langle T,W\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(T^\dagger W)$.

Suppose $T$ is symmetric and $W$ is antisymmetric. Then we may use $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$ and $\mathrm{tr}(X^\dagger)=\mathrm{tr}(X)$ (if we're talking about real inner product spaces) to reason that $\langle T,W\rangle=0$. (Can you do this?)

If $T$ were *not* symmetric, it would have nonzero skew-symmetric part. What would $T\cdot W$ be then if we were to set $W=T_\mathrm{skew}$? Can it be $0$?

Comment: It's clear that if $T$ is symmetric and $W$ skew, then $T \cdot W=0$. I already proved that. But I was interested in the converse implication @runaway44 So I think that what I am missing is your last paragraph. If $T$ has non-zero skew symmetric part, then

Comment: I could do $T \cdot T_\text{skew}=(T_\text{sym} + T_\text{skew}) \cdot T_\text{skew} = 0+ T_\text{skew} \cdot T_\text{skew} \ne 0$ because $T_\text{skew} \ne 0$.

Comment: To summarize, I can proceed as follows: consider $T=T_\text{skew} + T_\text{sym}$ Then $T \cdot W = (T_\text{skew} + T_\text{sym}) \cdot W=0 + T_\text{sym} \cdot W$. Now, by assumption, $T \cdot W = 0$, which thanks to the previous computation means $T_\text{skew} \cdot W$ must be $0$ for every skew-symmetric tensor $W$. Now I use the fact that if $$T\cdot S=0$$ for every tensor $S$, then $T=0$. So in this case, it follow that $T_\text{sym}=0$. 

Is that correct @runaway44?

Comment: @runaway44 could you plase give a check to my last comment?

Comment: Your second comment is fine for a proof by contradiction. Your third comment seems strange; in order to use the fact that "if $T\cdot S=0$ for all $S$ then $T=0$" you must first conclude $T\cdot S=0$ for all $S$, and we're not trying to show $T=0$ anyway (and also you can't conclude $T_\mathrm{sym}=0$ from the original hypothesis that $T\cdot W=0$ for all skew-symmetric $W$; you must conclude $T_\mathrm{skew}=0$ from that hypothesis).